# How to ignore the rest of the line?

Tags: c++

I have written a program that is graded by its speed, and I assume that generally I/O is the bottleneck even when the inputs are read from a file (and not manually inserted). In some cases, the program does not need the whole input of the current line and should just continue reading on the next line of input.

I have found `std::cin.ignore(UINT_MAX, '\n')` as an option. But, hypothetically, what if there were more characters on the line left? How could I just discard the complete rest of the line?

---

For those who wished for more details and an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
typedef unsigned int uint_t;

int main () {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    int t; std::cin >> t;

    for (int testcase = 0; testcase < t; testcase ++){
        // num entries in the next line
        unsigned int n; std::cin >> n;

        for(uint_t q=0; q<n; q++){
            uint_t height; std::cin >> height;
            if (height < 3){
                // do something
                std::cout << "Considering " << height << '\n';
            } else {
                // stop, finish reading line, then do next test case
                std::cin.ignore(UINT_MAX, '\n');
                break;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Finished testcase " << testcase << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

An example input file:

```sh
root@41d06f89ab19:/code# cat exmpl.in
2
4
1 2 3 4
6
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

And this example file of course works well:

```sh
root@41d06f89ab19:/code# ./exmpl.exe <exmpl.in
Considering 1
Considering 2
Finished testcase 0
Considering 1
Considering 2
Finished testcase 1
```

But let's say I had more input numbers remaining on that line than `UINT_MAX`. For easy demonstration, assume that `UINT_MAX` is `1` (replaced in the code):

```sh
./exmpl.exe <exmpl.in
Considering 1
Considering 2
Finished testcase 0
Finished testcase 1
```

In this case, the number `4` from the third line remains and is read as first number in the second testcase run. I would like to know how to ignore any number of remaining numbers on the line, even if they are more than `UINT_MAX`. The data is read from stdin.

Comment: How do you read the lines from your file?

Comment: @darclander from stdin. I have edited my question

Comment: @Jabberwocky I've added an example, though I thought my question would be general enough to not need one

Comment: @idclev463035818 yes. I won't need it for my submission, but I'd like to know the correct way of handling such a scenario where you don't know the number of numbers on the input line

Comment: @lucidbrot apparently you question wasn't clear enough as all comments were asking for clarification. Now it's much clearer.

Comment: there was an answer (now deleted) that included the correct way (but suggested not use it in favor of not nice solution). Anyhow, `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` is the maximum, there cannot be more characters in the stream

Comment: `UINT_MAX` is usually 4294967295. I think you can safely assume that you'll never encounter a text file with such long lines.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I also wonder why the post author has deleted his answer, I've just voted for undeletion.

Comment: @Jabberwocky imho it gives poor advice. The correct solution is also there, I just wonder why the answer suggests to not use it. Though probably undeleting and applying a small fix would be the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> more input numbers remaining on that line than UINT_MAX

You want to use

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

`std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` is a special value that instructs `ignore` not to count characters. Even if your line is longer than that (which is rather unlikely, unless you are running on a toaster), all of it will be skipped.