# loop involving "cin.fail()" running multiple times

Tags: c++, input, iostream, cin

I am having trouble with the following code. It is meant to keep asking for a valid input until an integer or double is inputted. It works as intended for characters, however when I input a string of length more than 1, it will run the loop multiple times. For example, the input "hello" with cause "Please enter a valid number" to be printed 5 times. Interestingly "h llo" will only print the sentence 4 times.

```
int gamenumber;

while(true)
{
    cin >> gamenumber;
    
    if(cin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Please enter a valid number" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        
    } else
        break;
```

I did manage to fix this issue by replacing "cin.ignore()" with "cin.ignore(1000, '\n')".

But regardless, it's bugging me that I don't understand why "cin.ignore()" alone doesn't fix this? Is there a way to fix the above code without using "cin.ignore(1000, '\n')"? (This is part of a homework assignment, and we may not be allowed to use "cin.ignore(1000, '\n')")

Thank you!

Comment: Did you want `std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `ignore` with the overloaded one, see this anser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955209/1292791).

Or you can just need to run `getline` to [drain](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the contents, but this way is slower and unnecessary.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
 
int main()
{
    double n;
    while( std::cout << "Please, enter a number\n"
           && ! (std::cin >> n) )
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        std::cout << "I am sorry, but '" << line << "' is not a number\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Thank you for entering the number " << n << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Instead of reading into a string (potentially allocating memory) that then gets destroyed it's better to use [`ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) correctly to [skip the rest of the line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955209/).

Comment: @Blastfurnace It's much better than `getline`!